# Extract facebook data from access token

Tags: facebook, web-scraping, extract, access-token

I'm trying to use this site https://www.oneall.com/ to add social login to a test site. After setting up the code and the login I still don't know how to extract user data from access token. Here's the link I get:

http://MYACCOUNT.api.oneall.com/socialize/redirect.html?provider_connection_token=ACCESS TOKEN HERE

I get this code by the call back page like this

```
if ( ! empty ($_POST['connection_token']))
{
echo "Connection token received: ".$_POST['connection_token'];
}
else
{
echo "No connection token received";
}
if ( ! empty ($_POST['connection_token']))
{
$token = $_POST['connection_token'];
$site_subdomain = 'myaccountname';
$site_public_key = 'public key';
$site_private_key = 'private key';
$site_domain = $site_subdomain.'.api.oneall.com';
$resource_uri = 'https://'.$site_domain.'/connections/'.$token .'.json';
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $resource_uri);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $site_public_key . ":" . $site_private_key);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 0);
 $result_json = curl_exec($curl);
if ($result_json === false)
{
echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl). '<br />';
echo 'Curl info: ' . curl_getinfo($curl). '<br />';
curl_close($curl);
}
else
{
curl_close($curl);
$json = json_decode ($result_json);
 $data = $json->response->result->data;
 if ($data->plugin->key == 'social_login')
{
  if ($data->plugin->data->status == 'success')
  {
    $user_token = $data->user->user_token;

    $user_id = GetUserIdForUserToken($user_token);

    if ($user_id === null)
    {
      LinkUserTokenToUserId ($user_token, $user_id);
    }
    else
    {
    }

    }
   }
  }
}
```

I need to learn how to extract data now and a little example about extracting the user name by this code.

Comment: I am using a different PHP Code to fetch the AccessToken and retrieve User Data ,,, Do you want me to post it or you need an update in your code?

Comment: the purpose of using onella.com is to afford multiple networks login so if you post your code that would be great and if you also update my code i'll be very thankful to you if you don't mind. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the access token to get the connection details from oneall using their api

> You use the connection_token to get the connection details (including
>   the user's Facebook profile data).

example
http://MYACCOUNT.api.oneall.com/connections/ACCESS TOKEN HERE.json -->>for json formatted data

[oneall docs](http://docs.oneall.com/api/resources/connections/read-connection-details/)

Answer (score -1):

Once you get the user's token, you then need to make a API call to Facebook, e.g. `https://graph.facebook.com/me/?access_token={$access_token}`

If the `$access_token` is correct, Facebook should return the user's details, including name, username and any other details you've asked for.

Comment: here's the test page hope you try it
http://www.mawk3y.net/glogin/onella.php
i get the access token but facebook tells me it's wrong (onella.come is the source that sends me the access token)

Comment: i've changed a little bit in the above code to get the user token instead of the connection token
$user_token = $data->user->user_token;
echo "user: ".$user_token;
and then use the code like this 
https://graph.facebook.com/me/?access_token={code here}
but i get message": "Invalid OAuth access token
test please http://www.mawk3y.net/glogin/onella.php

Comment: Are you sure you are using the access_token here and not the code that Facebook give you, which should be exchanged for an access_token?